# why my condition don't change the state in react js on submit?

Tags: reactjs

the problem is when i click on save i want to display the errorMessage  when the input are empty(the mandatory are field)but if the name,firstname and emaildress are not empty it will be a success message what is wrong thank you
ps: its only showing the same message when its empty or not

```
This is the function that i call

  getErrors = (indexOne, indexTwo) => {

    const test = this.state.test[indexOne]
    const administrator = test.administrators[indexTwo]

    const err = {

      name: hasErrorSimpleInput(administrator.name),
      firstName: hasErrorSimpleInput(administrator.firstName),
      emailAdress: hasErrorEmail(administrator.emailAdress),

    };
    return err;


  };

this is the condition:

handleSubmit = (event) => {

    localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(this.state.test));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.test));
     event.preventDefault();

  if(!this.getErrors){

      this.setState({
        successMessage: 'The updated data have been correctly saved',

      })
  }else
    if (this.getErrors) {
    this.setState({
      errorMessage:'fields are mandatory',



    })
  }
  }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
getErrors = (indexOne, indexTwo) => {
  const test = this.state.test[indexOne];
  const administrator = test.administrators[indexTwo];

  const err = {
    name: this.hasErrorSimpleInput(administrator.name),
    firstName: this.hasErrorSimpleInput(administrator.firstName),
    emailAddress: this.hasErrorEmail(administrator.emailAdress),
  };
  return err;
};

handleSubmit = (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(this.state.test));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.test));
  event.preventDefault();

  const errorObject = this.getErrors();
  const { name, firstName, emailAddress } = errorObject;

  if (!(name || firstName || emailAddress)) {
    this.setState({
      successMessage: "The updated data have been correctly saved",
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      errorMessage: "fields are mandatory",
    });
  }
};
```

`if(!this.getErrors)` instead of this try using this `if(!this.getErrors())`.

While assigning to handlers we write just the function name to pass the reference, but when you want the function to execute that time append `()` to it.

- I've corrected the spelling of "Adress" to "Address"
- I've added `this` before the functions in the `const err = {` declaration.
- I've changed the condition to check if any one of the error is there (i.e., either name, firstName or emailAddress)

Comment: i have administators undefined and i added the arguments to(this.getErrors(indexOne,indexTwo) THANK YOU

Comment: it 's not function can someone help me pls

Comment: Can you setup a sandbox ? There are a lot of unknown things for anyone to formulate a proper working code @zine31
I can update the code afterwards.

Comment: @zine31 since I don't have the whole code, I'll just try to fix whatever I can, check I've edited the code.

Comment: it's always the same error the problem is in get Errors, adminstrators is undefined

Comment: Can't hep you without other code (for administors etc.)